# Is rsync vs gcloud storage rsync better for remote sync?

Tags: ubuntu, sync, rsync, google-cloud-storage

I need to recursively copy many videos to our gcloud storage bucket from a local Ubuntu system while maintaining metadata, providing for continuation and validation. I am setting up some equipment to validate the following two options, but I was hoping someone could indicate which one aligns well with our goals.

---

##### I received a great response from Google.  Please review it at:

- https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Infrastructure-Compute-Storage/rsync-vs-gcloud-storage-rsync-syncing-question/m-p/705680#M5699

---

Options:

1. After mounting the gcloud storage bucket to a local mount-point and issuing the rsync command (see following) to transfer the file through the mount-point:

   - Should the local mount-point have the sync attribute? I believe that it should not have this attribute since rsync will be performing the synchronization and validation.
   - Will this configuration be fast or require several exchanges between rsync and the cloud?
   - Will metadata be preserved after the rsync has been completed?
   - Will an interrupted upload continue from the partially uploaded data?

   ```
   sudo rsync --archive --human-readable --verbose --partial --progress --human-readable --itemize-changes --stats src dst
   ```

   And the following command to validate the transferred file(s).

   ```
   sudo rsync --recursive --checksum --verbose --human-readable --itemize-changes --stats --dry-run src dst
   ```

---

2. Alternatively, if I used gcloud's CLI to perform the transfer directly from the local Ubuntu system to the bucket:

   - Will this configuration be faster than question #1, or will it require several exchanges between rsync and the cloud?
   - Will metadata be preserved after the transfer has been completed?
   - Will an interrupted upload continue from the partially uploaded data?

   ```
   sudo gcloud storage rsync --recursive --delete-unmatched-destination-objects src dst
   ```

   And the following command to validate the transferred file(s).

   ```
   sudo gcloud storage rsync --recursive --dry-run src dst
   ```

Comment: What metadata are you expecting to preserve? Using a native tool is much better than the FUSE file system which can only emulate Cloud Storage as a Linux file system.

Comment: Folder/File metadata, such as created dates, etc...

Comment: You must be very specific. Also, compare what metadata options are available in Cloud Storage. For example, the creation date is when the object in Cloud Storage is created, not when the original file was created. I recommend using a program to archive files such as zip or tar. That way the file system metadata is preserved.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, John!  It is an easy way to ensure that the metadata doesn't change.

Do you have any recommendations concerning the rsync vs gcloud storage rsync items? 

Thank you for your help!

Comment: They both do the same thing. I prefer to use native tools (gcloud storage or gsutil) to copy files to Cloud Storage over using gcsfuse and rsync because rsync has no support for Cloud Storage features. Use an archive tool and then either Google tool to copy the archive to Cloud Storage.